# NA problem when calculating mean by group

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, na

I would like to add a variable `new` through calculating the mean of a variable `old` by the group `groupID`.

1. create the data frame

   `df <- data.frame('old'=c('20','21',NA,'30','31'), 'groupID'=c(1,1,1,2,2))`
2. use within funtion to create new variable

   `df <- within(df, {new = ave(old, groupID, FUN= mean)})`

However, the NA in the 'old' make all the values in 'new' become missing values.
How can I ignore NA and still acquire the mean in my new varible?

the perfect result has to be like this:

```
df<-data.frame('old'=c('20','21',NA,'30','31'), 
               'groupID'=c(1,1,1,2,2), 
               'new'=c(20.5,20.5,20.5,30.5,30.5))
```

Many thanks from a beginer!

Comment: `df <- within(df, {new = ave(as.numeric(as.character(old)), groupID, FUN= mean, na.rm=TRUE)})` You column `old` is a factor.

Comment: `df <- data.frame(old=c(20, 21, NA, 30, 31), groupID=c(1,1,1,2,2));
df$new <- ave(df$old, df$group, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: the second reply works! thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df <- within(df, {new = ave(old, groupID, FUN= function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})
```

This in case you don't want to rewrite all your input data in a different (numeric) format